# How to express a Hermitian operator with a Unitary operator and a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm stuck in this problem, and is the last one!.

I have a hermitian operator A with its eigen-everything and I have to prove that it can be writen as $UDU^+$ where U is a unitary transformation, $U^+$ is its adjoint and D is a diagonal matrix.

I tried proving that $UDU^+$ could have the same eigen vectors but I couldn't, I really have no idea of how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Are you aware of the [standard proof given over at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a decomposition known as the Schur Decomposition or [Schur Triangulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)

if $ A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ then

$$ A = QTQ^{*} \tag{1} $$

you can transform this via hessenberg reduction. The proof works like this

$$ U^{*}AU = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & B \\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}  $$

by induction there is a Schur factorization $VTV^{*} $ of $C$

$$ Q = U\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & V\end{bmatrix} \tag{3} $$

$$ Q^{*}AQ = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & BV \\ 0 & T\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}$$